# I cannot login to Testlink after full congfiguration

Tags: testlink

After I install Testlink and Config Apache,Mysql and PHP,when I try to login to testlink using the password admin ,it shows error

DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 
 ==============================================================================

## 0  database->exec_query() called at [D:\xampp\htdocs\testlink-1.9.9\lib\functions\logger.class.php:708]

## 1  tlEventManager->deleteEventsFor() called at [D:\xampp\htdocs\testlink-1.9.9\lib\functions\logger.class.php:135]

## 2  tlLogger->deleteEventsFor() called at [D:\xampp\htdocs\testlink-1.9.9\login.php:213]

## 3  renderLoginScreen() called at [D:\xampp\htdocs\testlink-1.9.9\login.php:74]

Please help me out of this.

Comment: What do you see in /logs/userlog*.log?

Answer (score -1):

You do not have enough free space on Testlink machine. Type: df -h. Try to clean up log files.

Comment: OP has a Windows machine.